# How to cite a hardware catalog in bibtex

Tags: bibtex, citing

I would like to cite a hardware catalog of one (or more) manufacturers of devices that I'm working on for my master's thesis. Can anyone help me with some guidance on how to write the bibtex entry for such a publication ?

For example what I know about the catalog particular manufacturer is :
Hardware Catalog 2013, Ground Breaking Technologies inc., Utopia.

Comment: There's always `@MISC`

Comment: true, but that would be the last straw

Comment: If you use `bibtex` the last straw is to switch to `biblatex` (somehow recommended) and define a `@catalogue` entry type :-)

Comment: didn't know about that, thanks.

Comment: This isn't really a TeX question, it's a question about particular citation practice, which is very field dependent.  In APA style you would cite it like a book, with the company as author.  If it was accessed online it would be cited like other online resources.